Has the continued monitoring of the Voyagers probes been in danger of being discontinued, and if so, how many times?
I assume the continued monitoring of the Voyager probes has been part of the annual NASA appropriations and authorization, NASA Appropriations and Authorizations: A Fact Sheet, for example.
Have there been years when the monitoring of the probes came close to being cut?

You might add the Appropriations part as well - one needs both authorization to do the work, and an appropriation to do the work (two separate bills). It is not uncommon for things to be included in one and not the other (and then you can't do it).

@JonCuster Thank you
